# How to get a 'False' when judging if a part is beyond a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a Mathematica function or some simple expression that can be used to judge if a part is within or beyond a list? For example, `list={100,200,300,400}`. The desired expression with the argument `list[[4]]` would give `True`, but `False` for the argument `List[[6]]`. I can think of getting `Length[list]` and compare it with the index, but is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If your list contains numbers you can use

```
Quiet@NumericQ@list[[6]]
```

> False

or

```
Quiet@Check[list[[6]],False]
```

> False

Comment: Also `Quiet[Check[list[[6]], False]]`

Comment: The list does not have to be integers. Also, it is generally better to use `NumericQ` rather than `NumberQ` since `NumericQ` also recognizes numeric constants such as `E` or `Pi`.

Comment: yes numeric is better, I didn't say that the list must be integers. That's why I said "if". The second code is more general

Answer (score 1):

The function you ask for doesn't sound very useful. It is probably easier to just check the argument of the `Part` function. But here at least something that fills the requirement as I understand it:

```
list = Range[5]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)

ClearAll[LegallyIndexedQ]
LegallyIndexedQ[HoldPattern[Part[x_, n_]]] := (Abs[n] <= Length[x]) && n ∈ Integers
SetAttributes[LegallyIndexedQ, HoldFirst]

LegallyIndexedQ[list[[5]]]
(* True *)

LegallyIndexedQ[list[[6]]]
(* False *)

LegallyIndexedQ[list[[0]]]
(* True *)

LegallyIndexedQ[list[[1.5]]]
(* False *)
```

Answer (score 1):

This function tests if there exists in a expression *exp* a part at position *pos = {i1,i2,...}*.

```
myPartExistQ[exp_, pos_] := Module[{flag},
  flag = False;
  ReplacePart[exp, {pos} :> (flag = True)];
  flag]  


myPartExistQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6}]
myPartExistQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 1}]
```

> False
>    False

There are to cases of invalid position when using `Part`: Either the length of a sub-expression is too short, or the path specified by the position hits a atomic object.

`myPartExistQ` handles both cases.

It works with ragged array of arbitrary depth.